# Passing variable value inside setcontent in bolt.cm

Tags: twig, silex, bolt-cms

I'm using a framework called bolt.cm. A simple framework based on silex. There is a twig function to get records of specific contenttype :

```
{% setcontent products = 'products' %}
```

To get record and order them by specific field :

```
{% setcontent products = 'products' orderby 'datepublish' %}
```

Above will fetch records ordered by datepublish field. Now, I wanted to pass the orderby field from  GET parameter. I store the GET parameter in a global twig variable which passed from the controller, defined as `sort_by` variable.

```
{{ sort_by }}
```

Above will print sort_by value into html. In page : `/products?sort_by=datepublish` will set `sort_by` value as `datepublish` Now I'm going to combine this variable into setcontent function as described below :

```
{% setcontent products = 'products' orderby sort_by %}
```

Now I'm getting error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Attribute "value" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node_Expression_Name".") in "products.twig".
```

My question is simply, how to make sort_by recognized as a value inside that function ? Please don't tell me to do :

```
{% if sort_by == 'datepublish' %}
  {% setcontent products = 'products' orderby 'datepublish' %}
{% elseif sort_by == 'another_field' %}
  {% setcontent products = 'products' orderby 'another_field' %}

{# and so on for every single field #}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Bolt are you using? This should be possible since version 1.6. The release notes say:

> You can now use variables in your {% setcontent %} tags, like this: {% setcontent mypages = 'pages' order my_var limit other_var %}.

Comment: I was using a very old bolt release and yes, newer version has supported it now.